# Setting up Symfony2 with netbeans without the zip archive

Tags: php, netbeans, symfony, installation

I'm trying to start learning Symfony 2 framework, so I would like to set up my favorite IDE for that (on Ubuntu 12.04.01) But the problem is that In `options >PHP > Symfony2` window I'm supposed to give the path of Symfony2 zip download which I couldn't download from the website.

So I was wondering if I could set it up from the Symfony2 directory (installed with composer) which is located in `/opt/lampp/Symfony2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using linux as OS? It would be nice if you provide such information.

However I am using netbeans with windows on localhost (xampp). If you have both project and symfony2 library in one project folder, then you can just import project from existing sources and you will be fine.

When you have a seperate directory for symfony2 library, then you should just add symfony2 as library to your project. You have to navigate to project settings for this.

The latest php distribution of netbeans already has twig installed so this is great for template development with symfony2.

Good luck ;)